# On OpenCV. C++ Compiler is not able to compile a simple test program. Using Clang++

Tags: android, c++, opencv, cmake, ndk-build

**Goal:** Compile a external Library for Android using Cross Compile Build Script with Conan and OpenCV.

My Environment today:

- OS: *MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6*;
- Conan: *1.7.3* `../Cellar/conan/1.6.1/bin/conan`
- Python: *2.7.10* `/usr/bin/python` (Tried with 3 too)
- GCC/C++: *8.2.0* `/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-8 || /opt/local/bin/g++-mp-8` (Cited because clang use c++)
- Clang/Clang++: *9.1.0* `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin` (This is not the one the program is using)
- CMake: *3.12.2* `/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake`
- NDK used: *17*

**Problem:** The Open CV don't Compiler C++. The main message is

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 6.0.2
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 6.0.2
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++ -- broken
CMake Error at /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:45 (message):
The C++ compiler

"/Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++"

is not able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

Change Dir: /Users/<user>/.conan/data/OpenCV/3.4.1/ins/stable/build/4492059a128c69658616e0cf3d3f007e2ce6603c/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/ninja" "cmTC_4338c"
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_4338c.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
[2/2] Linking CXX executable cmTC_4338c
FAILED: : && /Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++ --sysroot=/Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot   -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/cmTC_4338c.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o  -o cmTC_4338c   && :
ld: library not found for -lc++
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
```

- CMakeTmp is a folder, empty.
- CMakeError has the same message after "..fail with the following output"

It is asking for **LD library**. But on LLVM folder don't have **LLVM-LD**, it was remove on 4.0 if I'm not wrong. I'm using 10.0. This is what has in my folder

[image]

- **Obs**: As you can see I don't know how to set up the Flag in the right way and don't know if this would change something.

**Code:**

Buildscript.py

```
build_dir = "build_Android_Debug"
conan_install_arguments = "-s compiler=clang -s compiler.version=6.0 -s compiler.libcxx=libc++ -s os=Android -s os.api_level=26 -s arch=armv8 -s build_type=Debug"

android_cmake_toolchain_path = current_dir_absolute_path + "/cmake-toolchains/Android.cmake"
conan_install_arguments += " --env CONAN_CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=\"%s\"" % android_cmake_toolchain_path

conan_install_arguments += " --env CONAN_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=/Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot"
conan_install_arguments += " --env PATH=[/Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin]"
conan_install_arguments += " --env AR=llvm-ar"
conan_install_arguments += " --env AS=llvm-as"
conan_install_arguments += " --env CC=clang"
conan_install_arguments += " --env CXX=clang++"

conan_install_command = "cd %s && conan install .. %s" % (build_dir, conan_install_arguments)

os.system(conan_install_command)
```

Android.cmake

```
set(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM /Users/vcanato/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/ninja)
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK /Users/vcanato/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/)
```

**What I already Tried**

On Buildscript

```
compiler=clang
compiler.version=5.0
compiler.libcxx=libc++
os=Android
os.api_level=21
arch=armv7
```

Obs: Gcc in deprecated, so would be good a solution without, but still didn't work.

```
compiler=gcc
compiler.version=4.9
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++
os=Android
os.api_level=21
arch=armv7
build_type=Release
```

On Android.cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4 FATAL_ERROR)
include_directories("/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0")
include_directories( "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0/bits")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -I /usr/local/include/c++/8.2.0/")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -X /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/g++")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/Users/vcanato/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++")
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/bin/gcc")
set(ANDROID_ABI arm64-v8a)
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_API android-21)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE /Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake)

set(CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK /Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/ CACHE FILEPATH "")
```

On CmakeList.txt

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/Users/vcanato/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/g++")
```

Before and after `project()`

Toolchains:

```
/Users/vcanato/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9
/Users/vcanato/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86_64-4.9
```

I even try to build my own [standalone toolchain](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain) and use [Conan cross building guide to Android](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/systems_cross_building/cross_building.html#linux-windows-macos-to-android)

**Similar Question On Stack and GitHub:**

- [CMake “clang++ is not able compile a simple test program”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26380407/cmake-clang-is-not-able-compile-a-simple-test-program-fedora-20)
- [“The C Compiler […] is not able to compile a simple test program” using CMake and Android NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41346745/the-c-compiler-is-not-able-to-compile-a-simple-test-program-using-cmake)
- ["The C++ compiler "/usr/bin/c++.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program"](https://github.com/OpenFAST/openfast/issues/108)

Comment: The message "is not able to compile a simple test program." isn't the *main* message (at least, it is not the only "main" one). It should be a line (like in the first question reference) "It fails with the following output:", after which you will found exact reason, why the compilation fails.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for the help. I just edited with the message that you ask, but looks like the same message before, thanks for any ideas

Comment: Hm, no, the message `No such file or directory` is new in your log. And the message `Make command was: "" "cmTC_27ba1"` looks suspicious: instead of empty quoted string it should be `ninja` (or absolute path to it). Note, that setting `set(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM <...>/ninja)` is **wrong**: you need to set *CACHE* variable instead: `set(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM <...>/ninja CACHE FILEPATH "")`. If you want to resolve other problems, you need to post your *full* toolchain file. You list two compilers, set another one in `CMakeLists.txt`, but CMake uses other one, probably, because of the toolchain.

Comment: @Tsyvarev this is my full toolchain file right now. I putted later what more I had insert, but they made no difference, so I removed. My `CMakeList.txt` has none compiler, it will work as Cross Compiler. What path I should put in CACHE FILEPATH? Ninja? just the same?

Comment: `<...>/ninja` is a replacement for your path. As for the last `""` parameter, it denotes documentation string and may be leaved empty (but it cannot be omitted). "My `CMakeList.txt` has none compiler" - the line `set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/g++")` is intended to set a compiler... (Anyway, it does it wrong: the line should be issued after the `project()` call).

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks, worked like a charm. If you wanna, put this as answer. Now I have another problem `ld: library not found for -lc++`will research a little.

Comment: I wonder what is `Android.cmake` file in your post? Googling for the file with this exact name finds nothing useful. Judging the file's content, as most of its `set` calls suggest, that this is a *toolchain* file. But setting `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` variable in the toolchain is *useless* - CMake uses the variable to find the toolchain file itself. The setting `set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)` isn't for toolchain too. In your first version of the post, you name this file as "CMake", so I suggested that it was `CMakeLists.txt`. Please, clarify meaning of this file.

Comment: @Tsyvarev you is right, `Android.cmake` is used in build script as toolchain file. (Line 5 buildscript.py). I'm not setting  `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` and `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`, you looked at "What I already Tried" session. This is not the file now, when I created this post the file only has two "SET's"

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by "It is asking for LD library.", but the error is about missed `c++` library. As far as I know, `clang` uses *external* (which is not part of llvm) linker `ld`. If your host `ld` is actually picked, than it is a problem by itself: the host linker can only process `x86-64` and related arch'es, not the `arm`. I cannot tell how to check that (probably, by running `which ld` from the conan's toolchain). Also, `--sysroot=/usr/bin` looks weird: normally, the directory `/usr/bin` contains only *executables*, but sysroot implies *libraries*, *headers*, and so on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180361/discussion-between-canato-and-tsyvarev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper way for specify CMAKE_MAKE_COMMAND in the toolchain is setting *CACHE* variable:

```
set(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM /Users/vcanato/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/ninja
    CACHE FILEPATH "")
```

This is implied both [by documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM.html) (if the variable is set by a generator, CACHE version is set), and in [this CMake mailing](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2013-November/056285.html).

#### More explanations

*Emptiness* of the first string in the message

```
Make command was: "" "cmTC_27ba1"
```

should be the first signal of "*something goes wrong*". Instead of the empty string it should be an executable corresponded to the CMake generator (or an absolute path to the executable). In you case the generator's executable is `ninja`.

Usually, CMake signals about the problem in more descriptive way:

> CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set

Comment: Sorry to remove the right tick, I thought that the problem was in another place, but still in the same. But now I put more informations after your right shot about the `CACHE FILEPATH`